# Elección de Calendario para añadir un evento iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, calendar, google-calendar

Estoy intentando añadir eventos al calendario de los dispositivos iOS, de momento he conseguir añadir un evento al calendario `defaultCalendarForNewEvents`, pero lo que yo quiero es poder elegir el calendario en el que quiero  añadir el evento.

Por ejemplo en la siguiente captura se ve que existe un calendario del iphone y después pueden haber 1 o varios de gmail

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Yo lo que quiero hacer es que **se puede elegir el calendario** en el que se quiera añadir el evento, no que el sistema elija el calendario.

¿Alguna recomendación?¿Algún ejemplo?

P.D: estoy empezando a programar con [objective-c](/questions/tagged/objective-c) e [ios](/questions/tagged/ios)

Código para añadir eventos que estoy probando y funciona:

```
- (void) addEventCalendar: (Evento_DTO *) evento {
    EKEventStore *eventStore = [[EKEventStore alloc] init];
    EKEvent *event = [EKEvent eventWithEventStore:eventStore];
    EKReminder *reminder = [EKReminder reminderWithEventStore:eventStore];


    event.title = @"Test Event";
    reminder.title = @"Test reminder";

    NSDate *cDate = [NSDate date];
    NSLog(@"current date  %@", cDate);


    /*NSDateComponents *startDateComponents = [[[NSDateComponents alloc] init] autorelease];
     [startDateComponents setDay:12];
     [startDateComponents setMonth:12];
     [startDateComponents setYear:2012];
     [startDateComponents setHour:12];
     [startDateComponents setMinute:18];


     NSDateComponents *endDateComponents = [[[NSDateComponents alloc] init] autorelease];
     [endDateComponents setDay:12];
     [endDateComponents setMonth:12];
     [endDateComponents setYear:2012];
     [endDateComponents setHour:12];
     [endDateComponents setMinute:18];
     [endDateComponents setSecond:20];*/


    //event.startDate = cDate;
    //event.endDate = [cDate dateByAddingTimeInterval:15.0];

    event.startDate = [cDate dateByAddingTimeInterval:((5*60*60) + (30 * 60) + 15)];
    event.endDate = [cDate dateByAddingTimeInterval:((5*60*60) + (30 * 60) + 30)];


    //event.startDate = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] dateFromComponents:startDateComponents];
    //event.endDate = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] dateFromComponents:endDateComponents];

    reminder.completionDate = [cDate dateByAddingTimeInterval:((5*60*60) + (30 * 60) + 10)];

    NSLog(@"startdate  %@", event.startDate);
    NSLog(@"enddate  %@", event.endDate);


    [event setCalendar:[eventStore defaultCalendarForNewEvents]];

    //[reminder setCalendar:[eventStore defaultCalendarForNewReminders]];

    NSError *error = nil;

    [eventStore saveEvent:event span:EKSpanThisEvent commit:YES error:&error];
    //[eventStore saveReminder:reminder commit:YES error:&error];
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Deberías poder obtener la lista de calendarios disponibles usando [el método `-calendarsForEntityType:`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/eventkit/ekeventstore/1507128-calendarsforentitytype?language=objc) de la clase `EKEventStore`.

Algo así:

```
EKEventStore *eventStore = [[EKEventStore alloc] init];
NSArray<EKCalendar *> *calendars = [eventStore calendarsForEntityType: EKEntityTypeEvent];
// seleccionar de alguna forma el calendario...
```

Y luego utilizas el calendario elegido en lugar de `[eventStore defaultCalendarForNewEvents]`.

Comment: Muchas gracias, funciona perfectamente la obtención de calendarios!!! ¿ Sabrías si hay alguna forma de mostrar esta lista de calendarios en un alert para seleccionar uno? es que soy un poco nuevo en la programación de iOS y ando un poco perdido.

Comment: Podrías mostrar la lista de calendarios en un *action sheet*, puedes [ver aquí la documentación](https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/ui-views/action-sheets/).

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda, me ha servido de mucho

Answer (score 1):

Gracias a la ayuda de @MarcosCrispino he dado con la solución a mi problema, que a continuación pondré la solución por si ha alguien le puede servir.

Primero de todo he creado un método para obtener los calendarios disponibles que sean locales y los de gmail, el código es el siguiente:

```
- (NSMutableArray*) getCalendars {

    NSMutableArray *res =[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    EKEventStore *eventStore = [[EKEventStore alloc] init];
    EKEntityType type = EKEntityTypeEvent;
    NSArray *calendars = [eventStore calendarsForEntityType: type];

    for ( EKCalendar *cal in calendars )
    {
        if (cal.type == EKCalendarTypeCalDAV || cal.type == EKCalendarTypeLocal  ){
            NSLog(@"cal nombre:- %@ ", cal.title);
            [res addObject: cal];

        }
    }

    return res;
}
```

A continuación para mostrar la lista de calendarios para que el usuario pueda seleccionar uno y se introduzcan ahí los eventos, he seguido el consejo que me ha dado Marcos de utilizar un `Action Sheet`, aunque he visto que estaba deprecated según algunos comentarios del foro de StackOverflow en inglés, por lo que he utilizado `UIAlertController`, quedando de la siguiente forma:

```
NSMutableArray* cals =  [self getCalendars];

if([cals count] > 0){//Comprobamos que existan calendarios

   UIAlertController *alert = [UIAlertController   alertControllerWithTitle:AMLocalizedString(@"calendar_dialog_info", @"")
          message:nil
          preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet];

   for ( EKCalendar *cal in cals )
   {
         UIAlertAction *calAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle: cal.title
         style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction * action) {

         NSLog(@"You pressed button %@ ", cal.title);

         [self descargarCalendario:  cal];
          }];

          [alert addAction:calAction];
   }

   UIAlertAction* cancel = [UIAlertAction
                                         actionWithTitle:AMLocalizedString(@"cancelar", @"")
               style:UIAlertActionStyleCancel
               handler:^(UIAlertAction * action)
               {
                    [alert dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

               }];

         [alert addAction:cancel];

         [self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
}else{
    NSLog(@"No hay calendarios");
}
```

Donde la función `[self descargarCalendario:  cal];` se encarga de descargar unos eventos de un servicio web y añadirlos al calendario elegido.

Dando como resultado la siguiente vista para elegir el calendario:

[image]

Y el código para añadir el evento al calendario seleccionado es:

```
-(void)addEventOnCalendar: (EKCalendar *) cal{

    EKEventStore *store = [EKEventStore new];
    [store requestAccessToEntityType:EKEntityTypeEvent completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error) {
        if (!granted) {
            return;
        }
        EKEvent *event = [EKEvent eventWithEventStore:store];
        event.title = @"Prueba";

        NSDate *cDate = [NSDate date];
        event.startDate = [cDate dateByAddingTimeInterval:((5*60*60) + (30 * 60) + 15)];
        event.endDate = [cDate dateByAddingTimeInterval:((5*60*60) + (30 * 60) + 15)];

        //event.calendar = [store defaultCalendarForNewEvents];
        event.calendar = [store calendarWithIdentifier: cal.calendarIdentifier];

        NSError *err = nil;
        [store saveEvent:event span:EKSpanThisEvent commit:YES error:&err];

    }];
    UIAlertView *alert=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Mensaje" message:@"Evento añadido correctamente en el calendario" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    [alert show];

}
```

Espero que le sirva a alguien de ayuda