# Problema al hacer carga masiva de eventos en el calendario ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-calendar, calendar

Estoy intentando hacer una **carga masiva** de eventos en un calendario de [ios](/questions/tagged/ios) ya sea local o en gmail (El calendario lo elige el usuario de la forma que describo en la siguiente [respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/34196/14088)) usando [objective-c](/questions/tagged/objective-c).

Añadir un evento con las funciones que he puesto a continuación me funciona bien, pero cuando tengo que hacer una carga masiva de por ejemplo 527 eventos (ya que estoy intentando añadir el calendario escolar de un alumno) no funciona correctamente.

Al hacer la carga masiva me inserta bien unos 100 eventos más o menos y luego empieza a fallar y se bloquea la app.

Los errores que me da son los siguientes:

> 2016-11-17 17:23:35.966 [230:11481] Calendar was not set: 1 Error
>   Domain=EKErrorDomain Code=1 "No se ha seleccionado ningún calendario."
>   UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=No se ha seleccionado ningún
>   calendario.}
>
> 2016-11-17 17:23:49.545 [230:12644] Connectioninterrupted!
>
> 2016-11-17 17:23:49.568[230:12587] Error getting changed object IDs
>   since timestamp 501092601.149441 from daemon: Error
>   Domain=NSMachErrorDomain Code=4097 "unknown error code"

Mi pregunta es la siguiente, **¿hay algún error en mi planteamiento de carga masiva o en las funciones que he hecho?** o por otra parte **¿Hay alguna otra forma mejor de hacer una carga masiva de eventos?**

Función que recorre la lista de eventos y los va insertando:

```
- (int) anyadirEventosCalendario: (EKCalendar *) cal {

    int num = 0;

    //se añade cada uno de los eventos
    for (int i=0; i < [calendario.eventos count]; i++) {

        NSDictionary * nextDict = [calendario.eventos objectAtIndex:i];
        Evento_DTO * evento_dto = [[Evento_DTO alloc] initWithEventos:nextDict];

        BOOL res = [self addEventCalendar: evento_dto calendar: cal];

        if(res){
            num++;
        }
    }

    return num;
}
```

Y la función que añade el evento al calendario es la siguiente:

```
-(BOOL)addEventCalendar: (Evento_DTO *) evento calendar: (EKCalendar *) cal{

    __block BOOL res = NO;

    if (!SYSTEM_VERSION_LESS_THAN(@"6.0")) {
        // iOS 6 and later

        EKEventStore *eventStore = [[EKEventStore alloc] init];

        //Obtenemos las fechas del evento
        Fecha_DTO *fechaStart = [[Fecha_DTO alloc] initWithFecha:(NSDictionary *)evento.dtStart];
        Fecha_DTO *fechaEnd = [[Fecha_DTO alloc] initWithFecha:(NSDictionary *)evento.dtEnd];

        // Formateamos las fechas a tipo NSDate
        // Fecha ini
        NSDateFormatter* df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [df setDateFormat:@"yyyyMMdd'T'HHmmss"];

        if (fechaStart.tzid == nil) {
            [df setTimeZone: [NSTimeZone systemTimeZone]];
        }else{
            [df setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:fechaStart.tzid]];
        }
        NSDate* parsedDateS = [df dateFromString: fechaStart.fecha];

        // Fecha fin
        NSDateFormatter* df2 = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [df2 setDateFormat:@"yyyyMMdd'T'HHmmss"];

        if (fechaEnd.tzid == nil) {
            [df2 setTimeZone: [NSTimeZone systemTimeZone]];
        }else{
            [df2 setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:fechaEnd.tzid]];
        }
        NSDate* parsedDateE = [df2 dateFromString: fechaEnd.fecha];

        //Obtenemos las rRules
        NSString *rfc2445String = evento.rRule; // Usando la libreria EKRecurrenceRule+RRULE.m
        EKRecurrenceRule *recurrenceRule;
        if (![rfc2445String isEqualToString:@""]) {
            recurrenceRule = [[EKRecurrenceRule alloc] initWithString:rfc2445String andTimezone:fechaStart.tzid];
           // NSLog(@"RRule: %@", recurrenceRule);
        }

        if(parsedDateS!=nil){

            [eventStore requestAccessToEntityType:EKEntityTypeEvent completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error) {

                if (granted) {
                    EKEvent *event  = [EKEvent eventWithEventStore:eventStore];
                    event.title     = evento.summary;
                    event.notes     = evento.description;
                    event.startDate = parsedDateS;
                    event.endDate  = parsedDateE;
                    event.location = evento.location;

                    if (![rfc2445String isEqualToString:@""]) // sólo añadirmos rRule si hay
                     event.recurrenceRules = [NSArray arrayWithObject:recurrenceRule];


                    event.calendar = [eventStore calendarWithIdentifier: cal.calendarIdentifier];

                    //[event setCalendar:[eventStore defaultCalendarForNewEvents]];
                    NSError *err = nil;

                    BOOL success = [eventStore saveEvent:event span:EKSpanThisEvent commit:YES error:&err];

                    if(!success){
                        if (err) {
                            NSLog(@"Calendar was not set: %li %@", (long)err.code, err.description);
                        }
                    }else{

                        //NSLog(@"EVENTO AÑADIDO");
                        res = YES;
                    }

                } else {
                    // code here for when the user does NOT allow your app to access the calendar
                    alerta = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:AMLocalizedString(@"Error", @"")
                                                       message:AMLocalizedString(@"errorPermisosCal", @"")
                                                      delegate:self
                                             cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                             otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
                    [alerta show];
                }
            }];
        }else{
            NSLog(@"la fecha de inicio es nula");
        }

        df = nil;
        df2 = nil;
    }else{

        alerta = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:AMLocalizedString(@"Error", @"")
                                           message:AMLocalizedString(@"VersionEvento", @"")
                                          delegate:self
                                 cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                 otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
        [alerta show];
    }
    return res;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finalmente he sido capaz de realizar la carga masiva de los eventos sin errores, he modificado los métodos quedando de la siguiente forma:

```
- (void) addCalendarEvents: (EKCalendar *) cal store: (EKEventStore *) eventStore {

    if (!SYSTEM_VERSION_LESS_THAN(@"6.0")) {
        // iOS 6 and later

        [eventStore requestAccessToEntityType:EKEntityTypeEvent completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error) {

            if (granted) {
                //se añade cada uno de los eventos
                for (int i=0; i < [calendario.eventos count]; i++) {
                    @autoreleasepool {
                        NSDictionary * nextDict = [calendario.eventos objectAtIndex:i];
                        Evento_DTO * evento_dto = [[Evento_DTO alloc] initWithEventos:nextDict];

                        [self addEventCalendar: evento_dto calendar: cal.calendarIdentifier store: eventStore];
                    }
                }
            } else {
                // Código aquí para cuando el usuario NO permite que su aplicación acceda al calendario
                alerta = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:AMLocalizedString(@"Error", @"")
                                                   message:AMLocalizedString(@"errorPermisosCal", @"")
                                                  delegate:self
                                         cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                         otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
                [alerta show];
            }
        }];
    }else{

        alerta = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:AMLocalizedString(@"Error", @"")
                                           message:AMLocalizedString(@"VersionEvento", @"")
                                          delegate:self
                                 cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                 otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
        [alerta show];
    }
}
```

Y la función que añade el evento al calendario es la siguiente:

```
-(void)addEventCalendar: (Evento_DTO *) evento calendar: (NSString *) cal store: (EKEventStore *) eventStore{

    //Obtenemos las fechas del evento
    Fecha_DTO *fechaStart = [[Fecha_DTO alloc] initWithFecha:(NSDictionary *)evento.dtStart];
    Fecha_DTO *fechaEnd = [[Fecha_DTO alloc] initWithFecha:(NSDictionary *)evento.dtEnd];

    // Formato de las fechas para escribir NSDate
    // Fecha inicio
    NSDateFormatter* df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [df setDateFormat:@"yyyyMMdd'T'HHmmss"];

    if (fechaStart.tzid == nil) {
        [df setTimeZone: [NSTimeZone systemTimeZone]];
    }else{
        [df setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:fechaStart.tzid]];
    }
    NSDate* parsedDateS = [df dateFromString: fechaStart.fecha];

    // Fecha fin
    NSDateFormatter* df2 = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [df2 setDateFormat:@"yyyyMMdd'T'HHmmss"];

    if (fechaEnd.tzid == nil) {
        [df2 setTimeZone: [NSTimeZone systemTimeZone]];
    }else{
        [df2 setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:fechaEnd.tzid]];
    }
    NSDate* parsedDateE = [df2 dateFromString: fechaEnd.fecha];

    //rRules
    NSString *rfc2445String = evento.rRule; // Usando la libreria EKRecurrenceRule+RRULE.m
    EKRecurrenceRule *recurrenceRule;

    if (![rfc2445String isEqualToString:@""]) {
        recurrenceRule = [[EKRecurrenceRule alloc] initWithString:rfc2445String andTimezone:fechaStart.tzid];
        //NSLog(@"RRule: %@", recurrenceRule);
    }

    if(parsedDateS!=nil){

        EKEvent *event  = [EKEvent eventWithEventStore:eventStore];
        event.title     = evento.summary;
        event.notes     = evento.description;
        event.location = evento.location;
        event.startDate = parsedDateS;
        event.endDate  = parsedDateE;

        if (![rfc2445String isEqualToString:@""]) // sólo añadirmos rRule si hay
            event.recurrenceRules = [NSArray arrayWithObject:recurrenceRule];

        event.calendar = [eventStore calendarWithIdentifier: cal];

        NSError *err = nil;

        BOOL success = [eventStore saveEvent:event span:EKSpanThisEvent commit:YES error:&err];

        if(!success){
            if (err) {
                NSLog(@"Calendar was not set: %li %@", (long)err.code, err.description);
            }
        }else{

            NSLog(@"Added Event");
        }
    }else{
        NSLog(@"la fecha de inicio es nula");
    }

    df = nil;
    df2 = nil;
}
```

Espero que le sirva de ayuda a alguien.